# HTML table read with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am in trouble with JavaScript. 
In my website I have a table, the last column is a textfield.

How can I read the table in JavaScript and save the content in an array. See the table below.

```
<table name="my-ajax-table">
            <thead>                    
                <th>Artikelbezeichnung</th>
                <th>Verkaufspreis</th>
                <th>Bestellmenge</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="d1">
                    <td id="drink_name">Cola</td>
                    <td id="drinks_price">6.98</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="order_amount" value="" name="colaamount"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="d2">
                    <td id="drink_name">Fanta</td>
                    <td id="drinks_price">6.98</td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="order_amount" value="" name="order_amount"></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
            <br/>
        <br/>
        </table>
```

Comment: What you mean save? As array of table cells?

Comment: id must unique field!

Comment: save means save -> the problem is how to read the table including the textfield - thx for downgrading the question

Comment: Hallo, soll das eine Art Bestellformular werden? Hello, Is this going to be an order form?

Comment: ja, es soll eine Art Bestellformular werden. Yes it's going to be an order form.

Comment: As szpal said, don't use ID's more than once. If you want to use the same name multiple times, make it a class.

Comment: wich id must be unique? later the content should be saved in db

Comment: is this your first time with html/web development? for an order form use the html-form-tag (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) - with it you can define fields that submits data to the server.

Comment: No it isn't the first time in web / html development, but I'm not a guru. I know how to implement a html-form. But in this case it is a little bit difficult. I need a table with content form a db, the last column of the table should be an inputfield, where the user can insert his order quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if i understand the question right, it should be something like this:

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
var total_array = [];

for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++){
    if(tds[i].className === 'drink_name' || tds[i].className === 'drink_price'){
        total_array.push(tds[i].innerHTML);
    }
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = total_array;
```

I made a div called test that shows the array on the screen, but ofcourse this is not necessary. Keep in mind i changed your HTML a bit as well (classes mostly).

https://jsfiddle.net/tbLxtmwg/

Comment: thx. this is working. But the last column of the table contents an inputfield. How can I read this?

Comment: I updated the fiddle to also accept the inputfield: https://jsfiddle.net/tbLxtmwg/2/

Comment: Yeah, it works and it's exactly want I'm looking for. Thx a lot. I'm going to learn more ande more JavaScript.

Comment: The main question is answered, but there is an additional question: I want to have the tabeldata in JSON. How can I implement this?

Comment: The problem is solved. The question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arrOftd = [];

    //Iterate all td's 
$('td').each( function(){
   //add item to array
   arrOftd.push( $(this).text() );   
    if($(this).find("input").val() != undefined){
        arrOftd.push($(this).find("input").val()); }
});

//iterate array
$.each( arrOftd, function(i, item){
    console.log(item);
})
});
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/1vr6p7jr/2/)